# 403 Forbidden when I urlencode parameters

Tags: php, apache

I'm using Wamp with Apach 2.4.2 on a windows 7 64bit system. During my tests, I tried to `urlencode` my url string.

I am getting the following 403 forbidden error message:

> You don't have permission to access /chi-linux/membersareaDev.php?doProfile=true on this server.

The links without urlencoding do not give an error. Since this is a dev box I do have access to http.conf (no changes). All of my code is in c:\wamp\www\chi-linux 
I don't get a permissions problem if I don't urlencode.

Here is my code:

```
<?php $url1 = urlencode("membersareaDev.php?doStatus=true?statid=10"); 
$url2 = urlencode("membersareaDev.php?doProfile=true");
echo "url=$url1";
?>
<li><a href="membersareaDev.php?doProfile=true">Profiles</a></li>
<li><a href=<?php echo "$url2"; ?> >Profiles Encode</a></li>
<li><a href= "membersareaDev.php?doStatus=true?amp;statid=10">Status</a></li>
<li><a href= <?php echo $url1;?>>Status Encode</a></li>
```

Any ideas as to what I'm missing?

Comment: for one, membersareaDev.php?doStatus=true?statid=10 has two question marks, rather than an ampersand.

Comment: I've tried various flavors to get around this including removing the second parameter (membersareaDev.php%3FdoStatus%3Dtrue) and I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

urlencode() encodes the question mark also so your URL becomes:

membersareaDev.php%3FdoProfile%3Dtrue

which is not proper, you dont need to urlencode your entire URL, just the individual passed parameters if you're worried about user input.

Comment: You should always be worried about user input! But having constant URLs is no threat, and they can simply be encoded the way that is needed, i.e. not changed at all because they are already valid. Note that you have to htmlspecialchars() the url if you created it in a variable and put it into HTML.

Comment: OK. I'm not worried about user input because these are variables that I'm generating. I think the '=' is being translated to %3D. Here is one of the examples when I only use one variable and do not encode the '=' membersareaDev.php%3FdoStatus=true. This still causes the error.